# Product detail - Error: Incomplete microdata with schema.org

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

Below is the code:

```
<div class="product-essential" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<div class="product-main-info">
                <div class="product-name">
                        <h1 itemprop="name">Test Simple product 55</h1>
                        <p class="long-name">Test Simple product 5SD</p>
                </div>
                <p class="-order"> Order #: test-simple-product-5</p>
                <p class="alert-urls"></p>
                <p class="product-type-data"> </p>
                <div style="display:block" class="price-box price-box-test-simple-product-5">
                        <p itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateOffer" itemscope="" itemprop="offers" class="old-price"> 
                                <span id="old-price-5" class="price" itemprop="highPrice"> $8.00 </span> <span itemprop="priceCurrency" class="price currency">USD</span> </p>
                        <p itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateOffer" itemscope="" itemprop="offers" class="special-price"> 
                                <span id="product-price-5" class="price" itemprop="lowPrice"> $6.00 </span> <span itemprop="priceCurrency" class="price currency">USD</span> </p>
                </div>
                <div style="display: none" class="price-loader"> <img src="http://text/-dev/skin/frontend/enterprise/default/images/zoomloader.gif"> </div>
                <span>
                <dl class="top-currency">
                        <dd><a href="http://text/-dev/test-simple-product-5?SID=bbru84lc96dd53bamsmrvj0ou2" class="us-currency active" title="US Site">&nbsp;</a></dd>
                        <dd><a onclick="switchWebsite('http://text/-dev/test-simple-product-5?SID=bbru84lc96dd53bamsmrvj0ou2');" href="javascript:void(0);" class="canada-currency" title="Canadian Site">&nbsp;</a></dd>
                </dl>
                <p itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemscope="" itemprop="offers" class="availability in-stock"> <span class="product-qty"> 99999991 </span> <span>
                        <link href="http://schema.org/InStock" itemprop="availability">
                        In stock </span> </p>
                </span>
                <p class="shipping-icon">Free shipping over $250</p>

        </div>
```

I am getting the error **Incomplete microdata with schema.org** in Product detail page.

Below is the snippets:

> Item
>   type: http://schema.org/product
>    property:
>   name: Test Simple product 55
>   offers:   Item 1
>   offers:   Item 2
>    offers:   Item 3
>    Error: Incomplete microdata with schema.org.

Comment: Are you really using this snippet? Do you use the *Google Structured Data Testing Tool*? I don’t get this error.

Comment: Ya I have use the Google Structured Data Testing Tool and still getting this error.

Comment: Even if you copy-and-paste this snippet from your question? Then there’s something wrong with Google’s tool.

Comment: Sorry forget to add one <div> tag.once again you copy and test it.you will get the error.

Comment: Did you get the error?

Comment: Yes, now there’s the error. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but I realised I don't need to worry about this too much since the actual example on the Google Structured Data Testing tool contains the same error message.. See here: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.overstock.com%2FOffice-Supplies%2FOffice-Star-Professional-Air-Grid-Deluxe-Task-Chair%2F2605023%2Fproduct.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mis-using AggregateOffer which should contain multiple offers - whereas you seem to be using it multiple times for single offers.

If you combine the "highPrice" and "lowPrice" into a single AggregateOffer, along with the "availability" from the third "offer" then the markup produces no errors (also I moved the $ sign outside of the "highPrice" and "lowPrice" spans):

```
<div class="product-essential" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <div class="product-main-info">
    <div class="product-name">
      <h1 itemprop="name">Test Simple product 55</h1>
      <p itemprop="productID">5SD</p>
    </div>
    <p class="transcat-order">Transcat Order #: test-simple-product-5</p>
    <p class="alert-urls"></p>
    <p class="product-type-data"> </p>
    <div style="display:block" class="price-box price-box-test-simple-product-5">
    <p itemprop="offers" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateOffer" itemscope class="old-price"> 
      $<span id="old-price-5" class="price" itemprop="highPrice">8.00</span> <span itemprop="priceCurrency" class="price currency">USD</span>
      $<span id="product-price-5" class="price" itemprop="lowPrice">6.00</span> <span itemprop="priceCurrency" class="price currency">USD</span>
      <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">In stock
    </p>
  </div>
  <div style="display: none" class="price-loader">
    <img src="http://text/transcat-dev/skin/frontend/enterprise/default/images/zoomloader.gif">
  </div>
  <span>
    <dl class="top-currency">
      <dd>
    <a href="http://text/transcat-dev/test-simple-product-5?SID=bbru84lc96dd53bamsmrvj0ou2" class="us-currency active" title="US Site">&nbsp;</a>
      </dd>
      <dd>
    <a onclick="switchWebsite('http://text/transcat-dev/test-simple-product-5?SID=bbru84lc96dd53bamsmrvj0ou2');" href="javascript:void(0);" class="canada-currency" title="Canadian Site">&nbsp;</a>
      </dd>
    </dl>
  </span>
  <p class="shipping-icon">Free shipping over $250</p>
</div>
```

If you can explain in plain language the business logic behind the offers you are trying to mark-up then I might be able to help further and more accurately.

Comment: But it is not working when there is a only single price on the product means if there is no high-price and low-price on the product, for this case it is showing "missing low-price error". So what to do in this case ?

Comment: Could you explain in plain language the business logic behind the offer(s) you are trying to mark-up then I might be able to help further and more accurately.